# Connect protege plugins

Tags: protege

I am developing two protege plugins. While they work independently, it would be beneficial if they could exchange status updates. What is the preferred way of communicating data (possibly unrelated to the ontology) between two plugins?

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Protege plugin implementation is based on the OSGi framework. Protege in specific uses Apache Felix for implementing the OSGi framework. So to know how to enable communication between bundles you have to look OSGi and Apache Felix. See [Apache Felix inter bundle communication](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-event-admin.html).

Comment: What is the preferred way of adding eventAdmin to a protege plugin's pom.xml?